# Check if its morning or afternoon in ruby

Tags: ruby

How can i print morning if the Time.new is morning and afternoon if its afternoon

00:00 - 12:00

12:00 - 00:00

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another possibility if you will be doing this test a lot (not that I am advocating monkey patching at the drop of a hat):

```
class Time
  def morning?
    hour < 12
  end
  def afternoon?
    hour >= 12
  end
end

puts Time.now.morning? ? 'morning' : 'afternoon'
```

Answer (score 8):

```
(0..11).include?(Time.now.hour) ? 'morning' : 'afternoon'
```

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
puts Time.now.hour < 12 ? 'morning' : 'afternoon'
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if Time.now.hour < 12
  puts 'morning'
else
  puts 'afternoon'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_time_of_day(hour)
    if (hour >= 5 and hour <= 9)
      return "early_morning"
    elsif (hour > 9 and hour <= 11)
      return "late morning"
    elsif (hour > 11 and hour <= 13)
      return "early afternoon"
    elsif (hour > 13 and hour <= 16)
      return "late afternoon"
    elsif (hour > 16 and hour <= 19)
      return "evening"
    end
end

# example call
get_time_of_day(DateTime.now.hour)
```